# "Immediately" 立即, 即時, 立刻, 馬上 etc

Tags: vocabulary

I'm trying to find a suitable translation for the word immediately. The dictionary has all of these words (I limited it to 4 in the title but there are over 10 results from what I can see).

Could someone list the top 3 most commonly used ways to express the idea "immediately" and describe the differences between each?

Comment: dictionaries often explain the range of applicability of different translations, see e.g. iciba which quotes 柯林斯高阶英汉双解学习词典 （COLLINS COBUILD ADVANCED LEARNER’S ENGLISH-CHINESE DICTIONARY）
.

Comment: cf。＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂（定价：４５。００元，请查看公共、学校或大学图书馆，check available libraries）立刻（副）／立即（副）（２４１页）立刻（副）／马上（副）（２４２页）立刻（副）／顿时（副）／眼看（副）（２４３－２４５页）下面仅仅请看关于＂‌​立刻／立即＂的条目：［相同］都是副词，在动词前作状语，表示动作行为、情况很快发生，或某个情况紧接着前面的情况发生，相当于＂马上＂。＂立刻＂书面语和口语都用，＂立即‌​＂多用于书面语，经常可以呼唤：１。考试结束的铃声一响，就应该立即放下笔，停止答题。（立刻✓）２。事故发生以后，有关部门立即组织人员进行调查。（立刻✓）３。立即停止‌​行动！。（立刻✓）４。接到报警，警察立刻赶到出事地点。（立即✓）５。放下电话，我立刻开车走往机场。（立即✓）。６。团长命令我们立刻出发！（立即✓）［不同］＂立刻＂‌​常和＂就，就要＂连用，用于口语；此时一般不用＂立即＂：１。等一下，我立刻就来。（立即×）２。别着急，警察立刻就到。（立即×）３。请把手机关掉，飞机立刻就要起飞了。‌​（立即×）。４。比赛立刻就要开始了，快点把电视打开！（立即×）。５。火车立刻就要开了，你赶快下车吧！（立即×）６。别说话了，考试立刻就要开始了。（立即×）。

Answer (score 1):

1. without delay 即刻﹐馬上

將食物烹調十分鐘後即刻上桌。

我一收到他們的傳真﹐就馬上回信。

2. very soon before or after something 立即﹐立刻

那個嬰兒剛出生就立刻被別人領養了。

3. very near to something  緊靠著

他就住在緊靠我們家樓上的那個公寓。

4. immediately involved/concerned/affected etc -very closely involved etc in a particular situation 直接

這個決定將通知所有直接相關人員。

Answer (score 0):

You, bring me the paper immediately.
你 立刻 把那堆纸给我。
I immediately understood what he said.
我 马上 就明白了他说的。
She immediately slapped him.
她 瞬间 甩了他一巴掌

Answer (score -1):

立即 立刻 are similar and common for your answer. They are focus on something should be done as soon as possible.

即時 is subtlely different than these above. In most case, this word is used for something just happen in the very seconds ago. For example 即時新聞 (latest news).

馬上 is same as 立即 立刻 but a oral word.