# Difference between 马上，立刻，直接

Tags: meaning, usage

What's the difference between 马上、立刻 and 直接? How do I use each word and in what situation is each word used?

Comment: Why down vote? Please give a reason

Comment: @TangHo please look at the poster's question history.

Comment: searched site？there are many results about 直接，also see https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/14085/immediately-%e7%ab%8b%e5%8d%b3-%e5%8d%b3%e6%99%82-%e7%ab%8b%e5%88%bb-%e9%a6%ac%e4%b8%8a-etc/14088#14088  立即, 即時, 立刻, 馬上 etc esp. comment #1

Comment: @droooze Honestly asking: Are these types of questions not appropriate for this site?

Comment: @StephenCowley the question as given in the question title is fine, but the question details contain very little in the way of research or understanding by the OP. Check out the tag `[difference]` to see some examples of better questions.

Comment: @droooze Gotcha. This makes more sense now: Not the question itself but how it was asked and how much work was put in prior to asking.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, we would use 马上 to imply that I’m on my way.

We use 立刻，to imply “immediately”.

直接 means directly or straightforward.

For example, when I was a high school student, I was naughty and always made teachers mad at me, so they would ask me “go to the office after class immediately!” (That’s: 立刻来我办公室！in Chinese.)
 And I would reply 马上来，which means I’m on my way. So when I describe this story to my friends, I could say, 下课之后我直接去了办公室（I went to the office directly after class.)

Answer (score 0):

see dictionaries，search web (using e.g. ....有什么不同／区别)，consult specialized dictionaries （see below) available at public or university libraries) "实用汉语近义虚词词典＂立刻（副）／马上（副）**［相同］** 都是副词，作状语，表示情况或动作行为发生很快。经常可以互换：１。都可以用于已经发生情况或行为：（１）最后的结果一宣布，小马立刻激动得哭了。（马上✓）（２）客人们一走，房间里立刻安静下来了。（马上✓）（３）演出一结束，礼堂里立刻向起了热烈的掌声。（马上✓）（４）老师刚宣布完这个好消息，同学们马上欢呼起来。（立刻✓）（５）下课了，教室的走廊上马上热闹起来了。（立刻✓）（６）又刮风又下雨，天空马上黑了下来。（立刻✓）
２。都可以用于将要发生的情况或行为：（１）刘老师让你马上去办公室。（立刻✓）（２）师张命令我们马上出发。（立刻✓）（３）张经理叫你马上到会议室开会。（立刻✓）（４）请大家立刻离开这个地方。（马上✓）（５）立刻出发！（马上✓）（６）立刻关闭手机。（马上✓）

**［不同］１。** 用于将要发生的情况时，＂马上＂修饰的行为可以是很短时间内发生的，也可以是较长时间内发生的，如几天、几周、几个月；＂立刻＂修饰的行为是在很短时间发生的，一般是几秒钟、几分钟、几个小时之内：（１）下个月马上就要高考了，学生现在学习非常紧张。（较长时间，立刻✗）（２）听说新校长下个星期马上就到，是真的吗？（较长时间，立刻✗）（３）今天是１２月２０号，马上就到圣诞节了。（较长时间，立刻✗）（４）老张马上就６０岁了，还能和年轻人一起打篮球。（较长时间，立刻✗）（５）你马上就要当爸爸了，怎么还这么马虎？（较长时间，立刻✗）（６）火车马上就要开了，可小明还没赶到。（短时间，立刻✓）（７）飞机马上就要起飞了，请大家系好安全带。（短时间，立刻✓）
**２。** ＂马上＂可以放在主语后，也可以放在主语前；＂立刻＂只能放在主语后：（１）马上电影就要开始了,可玛丽还没来。（立刻✗）（２）电影立刻就要开始，了可玛丽还没来。（马上✓）（３）老板一走进会议室，马上大家都不说话了。（立刻✗）（４）老板一走进会议室，大家立刻都不说话了。（马上✓）（５）走进房间，马上一股冷气扑面而来。（立刻✗）（６）走进房间，一股冷气立刻扑面而来。（马上✓）

For 直接 see dictionaries, can hardly be confused with 立刻 or 马上，